# MDL Component Not working with React

Tags: javascript, web, reactjs, material-design-lite, material-ui

I was following the Facebook's react tutorial and was playing around with it.
When i tried to integrate MDL with my page (from getmdl.io), its not working.

In my index.html; i have added links to their css and js files. I also installed mdl using npm.

My index.html:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>React Tutorial</title>
    <!-- Not present in the tutorial. Just for basic styling. -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/base.css" />
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.14.7/react.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.14.7/react-dom.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-core/5.6.15/browser.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/marked/0.3.5/marked.min.js"></script>

    <!--Material design things getMdl-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.getmdl.io/1.1.2/material.indigo-pink.min.css">
    <script defer src="https://code.getmdl.io/1.1.2/material.min.js"></script>

  </head>
  <body>
  <div id="content"></div>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="client/public/bundle.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

In my index.jsx file, which is being converted to bundle.js by webpack:

```
const LikeComponent = React.createClass({
      getInitialState : function (){
        return {likesCount2 : this.props.likesCount};
      },

      getLikesCount : function (){
        return {likesCount2};
      },
      onLike : function () {
        let newLikesCount = this.state.likesCount2 + 1;
        this.setState ({likesCount2 : newLikesCount});
      },
      componentDidUpdate: function(){
          componentHandler.upgradeDom();
      },
      render : function(){
        return (
          <div>
            Likes : <span>{this.state.likesCount2}</span>
            <div>
                {/*<RaisedButton label="Like" onClick={this.onLike}/>*/}
                <button class="mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-button--raised mdl-js-ripple-effect mdl-button--accent" onClick={this.onLike}>Like Me</button>

              </div>
          </div>
        );
      }
    });
```

I have added the button in render function.

The output should have a material design button, but the button doesn't change.

Output right now: [Button is plain HTML button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tuBOr.png)

Is there anyone who can help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In React you need to use `className` instead of `class`. The reason is that `class` is a reserved JS word and JSX compiles to JS. It is the same with the `for` attribute - you have to use `htmlFor`.

I must admit that I continue to make this mistake every day. Fortunately React reports this common problem by warning in the browser console.

In short change your code to this:

```
<button className="mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-button--raised mdl-js-ripple-effect mdl-button--accent" onClick={this.onLike}>Like Me</button>
```

Comment: Worked like a charm. Still new to React, so making these mistakes. Thank you.